# use html formatted uri in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to send mails via a webapi (Dreamhost). By accessing a url with encoded parameters you can define the email.

one of the parameters is the message in html format.

I use the open() method to acces the url but get a

> URI::InvalidURIError

I can reformat the url by using URI.parse and URI.encode but this reformats the html in a unwanted state.

Is there a way I can embed html and open the url in Ruby?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CGI.escape.

```
require 'cgi'
"http://example.com?message=#{CGI.escape('This is the message body!')}"
```